# (Unnecessary) markup in a Wicket form

Tags: java, wicket

While generating a simplistic form page using Wicket (version 7.5.0), I'm getting extra markup which seems unnecessary (a hidden field placed into a `<div>` with inline CSS):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" wicket:id="ItemForm" id="ItemForm1" action="./tf?1-1.IFormSubmitListener-ItemForm">
      <div style="width:0px;height:0px;position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-100px;overflow:hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="ItemForm1_hf_0" id="ItemForm1_hf_0" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <label for="name">
          <span>Item name:</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="p::name" wicket:id="name" value="">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="price">
          <span>Item price:</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="price" wicket:id="price" value="0">
      </p>
      <section>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </section>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relevant Java class is:

```
// Package name and imports omitted    
public final class ItemFormPage extends WebPage {

      @EJB(name = "ejb/item")
      Item it;

      public ItemFormPage() {
        Form f = new Form("ItemForm") {
          @Override
          public void onSubmit() {
            setResponsePage(new ItemDisplay());
          }
        };

        f.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel(it));
        f.add(new TextField("name"));
        f.add(new TextField("price"));
        add(f);
      }
    }
```

I'm new to Wicket, as is probably evident from the code. Is there a way to avoid generating the aforementioned seemingly unnecessary markup? In other words, am I missing something or should I report a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This hidden `input` is used to submit the form with anchor-based components like `SubmitLink`.

For example, you have a `Form` and you want to have two ways to submit it (with different 2 buttons):

```
Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        // central form onSubmit
    }
};

SubmitLink submitter1 = new SubmitLink("submitter1") {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        System.out.println("submitter 1 called");
    }
};
form.add(submitter1);

SubmitLink submitter2 = new SubmitLink("submitter2") {
    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
        System.out.println("submitter 2 called");
    }
};
form.add(submitter2);
```

When you click any of the two submitters, its name will be put to that input, and Wicket will find the correct `SubmitLink` component and call its `onSubmit()`.

Comment: With all due respect, this doesn't answer the question. Which is "What is the pair of <div> tags with inline styling generated for around this hidden field". At the first glance it doesn't make sense to decorate something invisible :).

Comment: As rpuch has explained, the hidden field is needed internally by Wicket for special form submits. Since it shouldn't be visible to the user, Wicket decorates it as 'invisible' as possible.

Comment: badbishop, I believed that your question was about that `input` and not its decoration. I still believe your question may be understood that way :) As for the decoration styling, I don't know exactly, but I agree with svenmeier. Probably, it was just a precaution, or maybe in some browser version, due to a bug, a hidden `input` could actually be visible. The code for that styling is in `Form` class (the very first declaration in Wicket 6), so this is not a bug in Wicket, it was done consciously.

Comment: I'd like to add that this hidden input isnt actually hidden, its the div wrapper that is hidden meaning that screen readers will find this input making any page using SubmitLink not WCAG compliant.